# How does heating up a gas affect the average speed of the gas particles?

Tags: thermodynamics, kinetic-theory

I think that heating up a gas increases the temperature of the gas. A higher temperature increases the speed of the particles in the gas.

However, there is a step missing from my answer to get full marks.

The step is that we note that a higher temperature means a higher kinetic energy. This then means a greater average speed of the particles in the gas

My question then:

Why are these two points spoken about separately? After all, is speed not kinetic energy and is kinetic energy not speed?

Would it be wrong to say that increasing the temperature increases the speed of the particles, which in turn increases their kinetic energy.

The ideal answer speaks about higher kinetic energy as if it causes higher speeds rather than higher speed causing higher kinetic energies.

Hope someone can help me clear this up

Comment: So you are not sure that "heating up a gas increases the temperature of the gas"? What is the definition of "heating" if it's not "increasing the temperature"?

Comment: @nasu no I’m not sure why the logic is heating -> rise in temperature -> rise in KE -> rise in speed rather than rise in temperature -> rise in speed (-> rise in KE)

Comment: No, the logic is not "heating -> rise in temperature ->". Heating does not cause a rise in temperature. Heating is rise in temperature. Or you have another definition of heating? What is it?

Comment: @nasu heating (e.g. providing energy) can either change the temperature of a substance or change the state of a substance. As we’re talking about a gas, only the former applies. Or do you disagree

Comment: This is the reason I asked you the definition you imply. If by heating you mean "heat transfer" then I agree with you. By this definition, during boiling phase the water is still "heating".

Comment: The average kinetic energy of the gas particles depends only on the _absolute temperature_ of the system. _The kinetic theory has its own definition of temperature_, not identical with the thermodynamic definition.$-$ do you know this? Check wiki

Answer (score 2):

Your question suggests that you think that the temperature of the gas, the average kinetic energy of the atoms in the gas and the average speed of the atoms in the gas are three separate phenomena which are causally connected. In fact, they are three different ways of describing one and the same phenomenon. In an ideal gas, temperature, average kinetic energy and the average square speed of atoms are each proportional to each other.

Note, however, that heat and temperature *are* separate phenomena. You can put heat into a gas without changing its temperature - if, for example, the gas does work by expanding.

Answer (score 0):

Say it any way you like, but keep in mind that the absolute temperature is proportional to the average squared velocity.

Comment: Problem is that I don’t get full marks if I say it any way I like

Answer (score 0):

You will need to understand the relationship between **temperature**, **speed** and **kinetic energy**.

### Prior knowledge:

**Temperature** is a measure of how hot or cold a body is. It is directly proportional to the average KE for an ideal gas. The constant proportionality is **$\frac32$$kT$** where $k$ is the Boltzmann constant.

**Kinetic energy** (KE) = $\frac12$$mv^2$, where the magnitude of $v$ is the **speed**.

### Answers to your questions:

Increasing the **temperature** increases the **average KE**, which increases the **speed**.

It is **wrong to equate KE and speed** because there is another factor, mass, which influences the KE. Plus, KE is **not** directly proportional to speed.

Based on the first equation, **temperature is only related to the average KE**, not the speed. Therefore, the second equation is required to calculate the relationship between temperature and speed. However, there is another variable, mass, in the second equation which does not allow a universal relationship between temperature and speed.

In this case, **increase in temperature causes increase in average KE, which then causes increase in speed**.

Temperature (T) = $mv^2\over3k$